# MS Access - create JOIN table to store value for every combination

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am working on an MS Access 2013 database.  I have two tables:

- Customers (28 records)
- Chemicals (34 records)

I need to create a table for usage rates for each customer for each chemical.

The rates will be entered manually (at user's request).  I am trying to determine how to create a new table where the customer-chemical fields will combine to be primary key.

The resulting table should have 28x34=952 unique records.

The goal is to then have a form wherein the user can select the customer, then the chemical, and edit the rate.

For any table/query creation I am comfortable using either the Access interface or SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will advise to create a new table containing 4 columns. The first column will be an 'id' it is going to be your primary key (auto-increment if you want), second column is the customer, then the chemical, and finally the rating. Then if you format your query to select 'rating' where customer='customer name' and chemical='chemical name', you should get the desired result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply.  Did a little more wrestling with it and used the following SQL to create the table:

SELECT customers.customer, chemicals.chemical
INTO UsageRates
FROM Chemicals, Customers

Then adding a blank 'rate' field to the table.